# How does one prove by definition that $a_n=\cos(n^2\pi) $ converges as $n$ approaches infinity?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, cauchy-sequences

I've studied the definitions of convergence and divergence, but I still cant see how to approaches these types of problems, I know that the sequences oscillates between $1$ and $-1$ but I can't show that using mathematical definitions, I thought of picking $2$ sub-sequences and showing that their limit is different and that implies that my original sequence diverges, any tips on how to pick these sequences, if this even solves the problem at all.

Comment: In the title you are saying that you want to prove that the sequence converges. However in the body you suggest approach how to show that it diverges.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence diverges because $a_{2n} = 1, a_{2n+1} = -1$ for all naturals $n$.

Comment: Is that by the cauchy definition? can you be more clear?forgive me i new to this

Comment: Not quite. The property that I used in the proof is that if a sequence $a_n$ converges to a (real) number $L$, then all subsequences of it also converges to the same value $L$. And there is no such $L$ for your sequence. Because if there were an $L$ then $L = 1$ and $L = -1$, contradiction !

Comment: Ah yes i understand now,can i also solve it by saying that "let {Xn}=(pi/2)*n and {Bn}=pi +2pi*n so if limit of cos(Xn) and the limit of cos(Bn) as n approaches infinity are equal then an converges if not it diverges ?

Comment: Not quite as well.

Comment: What if i take :{Xn}=pi +2*pi*n and {Bn}=2*pi*n

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $a_{n}\rightarrow L$ for some $L$, then we may find some $N\in{\bf{N}}$ such that if $n\geq N$, then $|a_{n}-L|=|\cos(n^{2}\pi)-L|<1$. In particular we have $|\cos(2N)^{2}\pi-L|=|L-1|<1$ and that $|\cos(2N+1)^{2}\pi-L|=|L+1|<1$, then $2=|(L+1)-(L-1)|\leq|L+1|+|L-1|<2$, a contradiction.